# Unable to pass a user input array to execvp

Tags: c, exec, strtok

This is my input function:

```
    int i,j,n,len,c;
    char *buffer = 0;
    size_t bufsize = 0;
    ssize_t characters;

    characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);

    len = strlen(buffer);
    buffer[len-1]='\0';

    if (characters > 0)
    {
        char *end_str1;
        char *token1 = strtok_r(buffer, ";", &end_str1);
        int count = 0, wordcnt;
        while (token1 != NULL)
        {
            char cmd[10][101];
            memset(cmd,0,sizeof(cmd));
            wordcnt = 0;
            char *end_str2;
            count++;
            char *token2 = strtok_r(token1, " ", &end_str2);
            while (token2 != NULL)
            {
                n = strlen(token2);
                strncpy(cmd[wordcnt],token2,n);
                wordcnt++;
                token2 = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &end_str2);
            }
            cmd[wordcnt+1][0]='\0';
            execvp(cmd[0],cmd);
            token1 = strtok_r(NULL, ";", &end_str1);
        }
    }
    free(buffer);
```

The only warning is incompatible pointer type, but my cmd array is a **ptr, so I don't understand what is wrong.

I tried equating it to **k, and then passing that into execvp. Didn't work.
I tried changing cmd into a **cmd, I think I did something wrong there, because it should have worked but it didn't.

Comment: what are you passing to buffer?

Comment: whatever commands I enter into the program like `cd ..; pwd` are stored in buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my `cmd` array is a `[char] **ptr`

No, it isn't.

It's a `char[10][100]` and when being passed to `execvp()`  it decays to a pointer to its first element, which is `char(*)[101]`.

Also you have an "off-by-one" error here:

```
cmd[wordcnt+1][0]='\0';
```

`wordcnt` had already been incremented inside the tokenising loop.

What you want is:

```
#define MAX_NO_OF_CMD_ELEMENTS (10)

...

        char * cmd[MAX_NO_OF_CMD_ELEMENTS + 1]; /* 1+ for the NULL-terminator */
        size_t wordcnt = 0;
        char *end_str2;
        count++;
        token2 = strtok_r(token1, " ", &end_str2);
        while ((NULL != token2)
               && (MAX_NO_OF_CMD_ELEMENTS > wordcnt)) /* Prevent writing
                                                         out of `cmd`'s bounds. */
        {
            cmd[wordcnt] = token2;
            wordcnt++;
            token2 = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &end_str2)
        }
        cmd[wordcnt] = NULL;

        execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
```

---

Also^2 `getline()` returns a `0`-terminated `char`-array (a "string") already. No need for this

```
    len = strlen(buffer);
    buffer[len-1]='\0';
```

Comment: What about doing the `token2 = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &end_str2);`? Is that included in the while loop?

Comment: When I use this loop for input, the program only reads the first word into all the places in the array. Did I make a mistake? http://ideone.com/fRxv5z (relevant code at the end)

Comment: No problem. However I think I have integrated your code into mine wrong, because pwd works, but echo doesn't. http://ideone.com/fRxv5z [relevant code at end]

Comment: Also the program ends after just one input. I have a while loop in my main function, so why is this happening? Is it because I am freeing the buffer in the input function?

Comment: BTW, you are aware that a succesful call to `exec*()` does not return?

Comment: Yes, have I made a mistake there?

Comment: Oh no... That means the progam will end there. I need to fork there, don't I?

Comment: Ok I have added a call to another function where I fork and then exec, but it has become an infinite loop. Any suggestions on how to fix it?  http://ideone.com/V3KAD8

Comment: @RosieRed: Make sure you call `token1 = strtok_r(NULL, ";", &end_str1);` after fork/exec inside the parent.'s outer while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are passing wrong parameters to function [execvp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp).

```
execvp(cmd[0],cmd); //this line
```

Its declaration is like this:

```
extern int execvp (const char *__file, char *const __argv[])
```

and you are  passing argument of type char (*)[101] where it is expecting `char *, const*` hence throwing incompatible error.

Comment: How do I fix it? Shall I create a **cmd array and then malloc to it and write to it and then pass it to exec??